# How to resolve kivy app crashing on startup on Android?

Tags: python-3.x, kivy, kivymd, buildozer

Here is the main.py file that I use for conversion.

```
from kivymd.app import MDApp
from kivy.lang import Builder
from kivy.uix.boxlayout import BoxLayout
from kivy.properties import ObjectProperty, StringProperty
from kivymd.uix.navigationdrawer import MDNavigationDrawer
from kivymd.uix.navigationdrawer import MDNavigationLayout
from kivy.uix.screenmanager import Screen, ScreenManager
from kivy.core.window import Window

from kivymd.uix.datatables import MDDataTable
from kivy.metrics import dp
from kivy.uix.anchorlayout import AnchorLayout
from kivymd.uix.dialog import MDDialog
from kivymd.uix.button import MDRaisedButton
from kivymd.theming import ThemableBehavior
from kivymd.uix.picker import MDDatePicker
from kivymd.uix.list import OneLineListItem
from kivymd.uix.menu import MDDropdownMenu

Window.size = (360, 640)


class AssetTypeDropItem(OneLineListItem):
    pass


class ActionDropItem(OneLineListItem):
    pass


class AssetNameDropItem(OneLineListItem):
    pass


class AddInvestmentScreen(Screen):
    menu1 = None
    menu2 = None
    menu3 = None
    
    def __init__(self, **kwargs):
        super(AddInvestmentScreen, self).__init__(**kwargs)
        
    def on_enter(self, *args):
        asset_type_list = ["Select Asset", "Digital Gold"]
        action_list = ["Buy", "Sell"]
        asset_name = ["test"]

        asset_type_dropdown_items = [
            {
                "viewclass": "AssetTypeDropItem",
                "height": dp(40),
                "text": f"{i}",
                "on_release": lambda x=f"{i}": self.set_item_assettype(x),
            }
            for i in asset_type_list
        ]
        self.menu1 = MDDropdownMenu(
            caller=self.ids.asset_type_dropdown,
            items=asset_type_dropdown_items,
            position="bottom",
            width_mult=2,
        )

        action_dropdown_items = [
            {
                "viewclass": "ActionDropItem",
                "height": dp(40),
                "text": f"{i}",
                "on_release": lambda x=f"{i}": self.set_item_action(x),
            }
            for i in action_list
        ]
        self.menu2 = MDDropdownMenu(
            caller=self.ids.action_dropdown,
            items=action_dropdown_items,
            position="bottom",
            width_mult=2,
        )

        asset_name_dropdown_items = [
            {
                "viewclass": "AssetNameDropItem",
                "height": dp(40),
                "text": f"{i}",
                "on_release": lambda x=f"{i}": self.set_item_asset_name(x),
            }
            for i in asset_name
        ]
        self.menu3 = MDDropdownMenu(
            caller=self.ids.asset_name,
            items=asset_name_dropdown_items,
            position="bottom",
            width_mult=4,
        )

    def set_item_assettype(self, text_item):
        self.ids.asset_type_dropdown.set_item(text_item)
        self.menu1.dismiss()

    def set_item_action(self, text_item):
        self.ids.action_dropdown.set_item(text_item)
        self.menu2.dismiss()

    def set_item_asset_name(self, text_item):
        self.ids.asset_name.text = text_item
        self.menu3.dismiss()

    def date_picker(self):
        dialog =MDDatePicker()
        dialog.bind(on_save=self.set_previous_date)
        dialog.open()

    def set_previous_date(self, instance, value, date_rang):
        self.ids.date_picker_label.text = (
            f"{value.day}.{value.month}.{value.year}"
        )


class DashboardScreen(Screen):
    pass


class DigitalGoldScreen(Screen):

    def load_table(self):
        layout = AnchorLayout()
        self.data_tables = MDDataTable(
            pos_hint={"center_x": .5, "center_y": .5},
            size_hint=(0.9, 0.6),
            column_data=[("Asset Name", dp(30)),
                         ("Quantity", dp(20)),
                         ("Investment", dp(20)),
                         ("Sell Price/g", dp(20)),
                         ("Investment Value", dp(20)),
                         ("Profit", dp(20)),
                         ("Profit Percent", dp(20))])
        self.add_widget(self.data_tables)
        return layout

    def on_pre_enter(self, *args):
        self.load_table()


class ContentNavigationDrawer(BoxLayout):
    screen_manager = ObjectProperty()
    nav_drawer = ObjectProperty()


sm = ScreenManager()
sm.add_widget(DashboardScreen(name='screen-dash'))
sm.add_widget(DigitalGoldScreen(name='screen-dgld'))
sm.add_widget(AddInvestmentScreen(name='screen-addinvestments'))




class MoneyManagerApp(MDApp, ThemableBehavior, Screen):
    def __init__(self, **kwargs):
        super().__init__(**kwargs)



    def build(self):
        pass


if __name__ == "__main__":
    MoneyManagerApp().run()
```

Here is the .kv file.

```
Screen:

    MDToolbar:
        id: toolbar
        pos_hint: {"top": 1}
        elevation: 10
        title: "Dashboard"
        left_action_items: [["menu", lambda x: nav_drawer.set_state("open")]]


    MDNavigationLayout:
        ScreenManager:
            id: screen_manager


            DashboardScreen:
            DigitalGoldScreen:
            AddInvestmentScreen:



        MDNavigationDrawer:
            id: nav_drawer

            ContentNavigationDrawer:
                screen_manager: screen_manager
                nav_drawer: nav_drawer

<AssetTypeDropItem>:
    text: root.text

<AddInvestmentScreen>:
    name: 'screen-addinvestments'

    MDBoxLayout:
        spacing: "20dp"
        orientation: "vertical"
        adaptive_size: True
        pos_hint: {"center_x":.5, "center_y":.5}

        MDBoxLayout:
            orientation: "vertical"
            adaptive_size: True
            spacing: "24dp"

            MDRaisedButton:
                text: "Select Investment Date"
                on_release: root.date_picker()

            MDLabel:
                id: date_picker_label
                adaptive_size: False
                halign: "center"
                text: "01.01.20"

        MDDropDownItem:
            id: asset_type_dropdown
            text: "Select Asset"
            current_item: "Select Asset"
            on_release: root.menu1.open()

        MDDropDownItem:
            id: action_dropdown
            text: "Select Action"
            current_item: "Select Action"
            on_release: root.menu2.open()

        MDTextField:
            id: asset_name
            size_hint_x: None
            width: "200dp"
            hint_text: "Asset Name"
            on_focus: if self.focus: root.menu3.open()

        MDTextField:
            id: quantity
            input_filter: "float"
            hint_text: "Enter quantity"

        MDTextField:
            id: priceperunit
            input_filter: "float"
            hint_text: "Enter price/unit"



<DashboardScreen>:
    name: 'screen-dash'

    MDFloatingActionButton:
        icon: "plus"
        elevation: 8
        pos_hint: {"center_x": .85, "center_y":.1}
        on_press:
            root.manager.current = "screen-addinvestments"
            app.root.ids.toolbar.title = "Add Investments"


<DigitalGoldScreen>:
    name: 'screen-dgld'


    MDRectangleFlatButton:
        text: 'Back'
        pos_hint: {'center_x':0.5,'center_y':0.1}
        on_press: root.manager.current = 'screen-dash'

    MDIconButton:
        icon: "refresh"
        elevation:10
        pos_hint: {"center_x": .9, "center_y": .85}
        user_font_size: "40sp"

<ContentNavigationDrawer>:

    ScrollView:

        MDList:

            OneLineListItem:
                text: "Digital Gold"
                on_press:
                    root.nav_drawer.set_state("close")
                    root.screen_manager.current = "screen-dgld"
                    app.root.ids.toolbar.title = "Digital Gold"


            OneLineListItem:
                text: "Dashboard"
                on_press:
                    root.nav_drawer.set_state("close")
                    root.screen_manager.current = "screen-dash"
                    app.root.ids.toolbar.title = "Dashboard"
```

Whenever I create a build and transfer it to any of my devices, the app crashes everytime on startup and therefore never starts. I am using the latest version of all libraries and it didn't happen in the past. Though this app is based on a different kivy version than my previous experiments of building apps, I don't think that is responsible for it or maybe, idk.

If anymore details are required, I can readily publish them.

python version: 3.8
kivy version: 2.0.0

Comment: Try connecting an Android device to your PC (via USB) and run `buildozer -v android debug deploy run logcat > my_log.txt`. Then look in the file `my_log.txt` for hints as to what is happening.

Comment: @JohnAnderson I did this but I don't see an error showing in the file though I don't understand much. How should I share the log file?

Google Drive Link: https://drive.google.com/file/d/1Kg_B9ufPdRc3sAqlMgEghwyxQW8GTn08/view?usp=sharing

Comment: The vast majority of that file is just the log of buildozer building the `apk`. Very near the end of the file, there is a line: `List of devices attached` without any devices listed. Did you have your Android device attached?

Comment: I did have it attached.

Comment: @JohnAnderson I have updated the above mentioned file with a fresh attempt. This time it shows a device attached. When the app is installed and opened on the device it crashes and the terminal goes blank indefinetly. As soon as I remove the cable, buildozer ends.

Comment: Please follow this link to the log https://drive.google.com/file/d/1lNHLo0krzbBjvtKvh9mVIxMlIbjHgfp_/view?usp=sharing

Comment: Could you please show us the full buildozer.spec file?

Comment: @jbsidisJosuéCarranza here is the link to the buildozer file, I have only added kivymd in the requirements section and changed logcat to level 2 rest everything has been kept unchanged since the installation of buildozer. https://drive.google.com/file/d/1WUsizCiMS1lmQsBeiOk7fbShKeyRrUjP/view?usp=sharing

Comment: The error message in your log file says `Exception: The version of Kivy installed on this system is too old. (You have 1.11.1, but the application requires 2.0.0)`.

Comment: @JohnAnderson How do you find what's the error in so many lines of code?

Comment: One way is to search for words like `Exception` or `Error`.

Answer (score 0):

I tried the same, and failed several times. I think you're trying this with Google Colaboratory, but it isn't that powerful.
I converted my .py to .apk throught linux terminal through a Virtual Machine, such as VMware/OracleVMvritualbox etc.

[Here is about the whole process.](https://towardsdatascience.com/3-ways-to-convert-python-app-into-apk-77f4c9cd55af)